# React can't update on IE 10

Tags: reactjs, internet-explorer, console

I'm using react-boilerplate to build an app and everything works fine on Chrome and FF, but on IE, it doesn't.
Example: I have a list, after delete an item, it should disapear from the list.
It works on Chrome and FF.
On IE, it only works if I open an dev tool.
I tried to import 'console-polyfill' or add 'webpack-strip' in webpack loaders but none of these works.

--UPDATE--
Just find out something, 1st time go to list view, saga calls to api getlist (using axios) to get items, after delete, it calls getlist again but this time, it does not really call to api (I console log on backend and there is no request to it), but the response is the one from the 1st time request, so the list can't be update.

--UPDATE 2--
Okay i got it, IE still have cache from the first call using method GET. That's why

Comment: did u add babel-polyfill ?

Comment: yes I added it in app.js

Comment: What are the errors you're getting? Questions like these are hard to answer when there are no code examples and / or versions information.

Comment: unluckily, there is no error

Comment: I comeback with more information: